# Convert set to json array using java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Following is my code can it be optimized for java 8 and can it be more efficient?

```
public String LanguageString(Set<Locale> languageSet) throws Exception {
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONObject tempj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();
try {
  for (Locale locale : languageSet) {
    if (locale != null) {
      tempj = new JSONObject();
      tempj.put("lcode", locale.toLanguageTag());
      tempj.put("ldisplay", locale.getDisplayName());
      jArr.put(tempj);
    }
  }
  json.put("root", jArr);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  //
}
return json.toString();
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty fine to me, don't think you need to do more.

Comment: for code optimization/ review use `code review` --> (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you currently have a performance problem with it? If not, why bother?

Comment: if you declare a `Language` class with `lcode` & `ldisplay` properties to wrap a `Locale`, you'll found that is easy to convert to `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Java 8 and Stream API you can use `stream`, `map` and `reduce` to create your final `JSONObject`, e.g.

```
public static String languageStringUsingStream(Set<Locale> locales) {
    return new JSONObject()
            .put("root", locales.stream()
                    .map(locale -> new JSONObject()
                            .put("lcode", locale.toLanguageTag())
                            .put("ldisplay", locale.getDisplayName(Locale.ENGLISH))
                    )
                    .reduce(new JSONArray(), JSONArray::put, (a, b) -> a))
            .toString();
}
```

Here you can find a complete example:

> https://gist.github.com/wololock/27bd296fc894f6f4594f997057218fb3